# Вывод строк из файла TXT

Tags: php

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку скрипт каждый раз выдавал новую строку из файла TXT.
Сначала первую, потом вторую, потом третью и так до последней

Пока допер как вывести первую. А дальше затупил, хотя понимаю, что должно быть легко

```
<?php
function stroka($i){
    $f = file ('file.txt');
    $cnt = count ($f);
    $str = '';
    if ($i < $cnt and $i>=0) {
        $str = trim ($f[$i]);
        echo $str;
    }
}
echo stroka(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно таким образом решить:

```php
<?php
function stroka($i){
    $f = file ('text.txt');
    $cnt = count ($f);
    $str = '';
    if ($i < $cnt and $i>=0) {
        $str = trim ($f[$i]);
        echo $str;
    }
}
$z = 0;
if(isset($_POST['next'])){
    $z = $_POST['z'] + 1;
}
echo stroka($z);
?>
<form method="post">
    <input name="z" value="<?php echo $z;?>" hidden>
    <button name="next">Следующая строка</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

В [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php) есть [пример](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php#refsect1-function.file-examples)

```
// Получает содержимое файла в виде массива. В данном примере мы используем
// обращение по протоколу HTTP для получения HTML-кода с удаленного сервера.
$lines = file('http://www.example.com/');
// Осуществим проход массива и выведем содержимое в виде HTML-кода вместе с номерами строк.
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Строка #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
```

Вот по аналогии и сделайте

Comment: Не является ответом.

Comment: Это с чего это?

Answer (score -1):

Для решения задачи можно использовать либо форму и каждый раз страницу перегружать, либо использовать javascript и подгружать через ajax данные.

В первом варианте можно каждый раз при загрузке страницу в форму добавлять скрытый инпут со значением равным текущей строке. При нажатии кнопки форма отправляется на этот же файл и показывает следующую строку относительно индекса в скрытом инпуте и в новой форме указывает текущую строку.

Во втором варианте, можно сказать, что возможности практически безграничны. Тут лишь фантазия может подвести. Например вы загружаете новую строку через ajax, старая строка медленно исчезает и появляется только что загруженная, которая разлетается взрывом и на ее месте появляется третья. Это лишь пример, можно и просто через каждую секунду новую строку добавлять в dom html страницы ))

Comment: Ну и за что минус? То что я привел план что делать, не значит, что это не ответ. Дал автору направления, в которых можно действовать, а не написал за него код. Не написан код и сразу в минус. Вон человек по предложенной мною первой схеме решения, написал за автора код и получил плюс... Шикарно)